# Most efficient way to use values of Matrix as row indices to lookup values in another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am repeatetly drawing large matrices with random values from a Monte Carlo Simulation. As I explore a large parameter space, the simulation will most likely run for several days, therefore I am trying to find most efficient way to shave off as much time as possible. Consider the following code with a 500x18 Matrix as an example.

```
U = matrix(sample.int(500, size = 500*18, replace = TRUE), nrow = 500, ncol = 18)
X = matrix(nrow= 500, ncol = 18)
Marginals = matrix(runif(500*18, min = 0, max = 1),500,18)

for (i in 1:18){
  for (k in 1:500){
    X[k,i] =  Marginals[U[k,i],i]

  }  
}
```

The randomly drawn values in U serve as the row index, while the col index is provided by column of the respective U.

I know that loops are usually not the R away, is there a more efficient way to use e.g. `apply` here?

By Yogos Suggesiton, the most efficient code can make due without the k loop:

```
U = matrix(sample.int(500, size = 500*18, replace = TRUE), nrow = 500, ncol = 18)
X = matrix(nrow= 500, ncol = 18)
Marginals = matrix(runif(500*18, min = 0, max = 1),500,18)

for (i in 1:18){

  X[, i] <- Marginals[U[, i], i]

}
```

Comment: `for (i in 1:18) X[, i] <-  Marginals[U[, i], i]`

Comment: eventually `X <- replicate(18, sample(runif(500), repl=TRUE))` is equivalent to your code.

Comment: Thanks Yogo, the actual numbers in U are not uniformly distributed, but drawn by a more complex function (copula). I will edit your suggestion as the solution, thank you very much

Comment: I suggest to remove the *answer* from the *question*. Then please accept the answer which @jogo provided in order to indicate that you have found an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up by calculating column by column:

```
for (i in 1:18) X[, i] <- Marginals[U[, i], i]
```

Eventually the following is equivalent to your code:

```
X <- replicate(18, sample(runif(500), repl=TRUE))
```

(this will not be much faster than my first variant, but the code is more compact)